# Chrome not prefilling form

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I have a form that I would like to have chrome autofill or prefill (I'm using Mac Chrome 26.0.1410.65 on Mountain Lion).  The purpose of this is to demonstrate the autocomplete standards: I'd like to show either the fields prefilled on load, or if the user starts typing their first name it will auto-fill both names.

I'm using autocomplete and the entire page is below, with just two fields.

I submit, then the next time I visit the page, I have to start typing into each field to get the drop-down for auto-complete.  No matter what I do on the first field, I have to tab to the second and start typing there.

I'd like it to fill in all the fields (well, both) when I accept a value in the first field.  How do I get that?  I see it happening in commercial websites, where starting to type in a single field and it pre-fills many other fields. (even if there is a yellow background)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Autofill test</title></head>
  <body>
    <form name="nameform" action="?go" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="givenname" autocomplete="given-name">
        <input type="text" name="familyname" autocomplete="family-name">
        <button type="submit">Save values</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen the other questions that indicate I have to use POST, and there cannot be hyphens in the name.  I have also tried `x-autocompletetype` and `autocomplete`.  I've also tried without the DOCTYPE (I'm getting desperate), and renaming the fields "fname" or "firstname" etc.  Nothing appears to work.

Is there something I'm missing?